# issue with sql query finding records between dates in SQL

Tags: sql

i have this query which i use in order to get info of records between two dates.

```
$start=$_REQUEST['from'];
$end=$_REQUEST['to'];
$startd = str_replace('/', '-', $start);
echo $start1=date('Ymd', strtotime($startd));
$endd = str_replace('/', '-', $end);
echo $end1=date('Ymd', strtotime($endd));
echo $data ="SELECT * from forma 
  WHERE DATE(data) BETWEEN '".$start1."' AND '".$end1."' ";
  $res = odbc_exec($connection, $data) or die(odbc_error());
```

I get this error :

```
]'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name., SQL
```

But how can i solve this in SQL? 
`data` is a `varchar` type..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data` consists of `Ymd` formatted date strings, you should be able to to:

```
$data="SELECT * from forma WHERE data BETWEEN '".$start1."' AND '".$end1."'";
```

You can compare strings: `'2012' > '2011'` and `'b' > 'a'` and, in your  case, `'20121214' > '20120701'`, for example.

Comment: Yes I understood - I was only referring to the formatting in that column. If it is `20121214` for today, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
echo $data ="select * FROM forma WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '".$start1."' AND '".$end1."' ;
```

Also you can add an extra wrapping with the mysql function to create a date format you like. For that use date_format()

Comment: it gives me an error 
str_to_date' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Wich version of MySQL you are using? I use the latest version of mysql. When you use '%d/%m/%Y' the value of the varchar has to be like 01/01/2012.

Comment: The issue is, i'm on SQL Server as i've mentioned above :)